# The difference in strings in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am using Tableau Server version 10.4.3
I have a dimension `rTime` which has string value. the entries in `rTime` is of like this
`May 10, 2019 8:59:56.303 PM UTC`
I want to check whether the `rTime` is today or not. I cannot use `DateParse` since my server doesn't have this functionality.

I created a calculated field `CheckrTime` with below content :

```
STR(LEFT(SPLIT([rTime],':',1),LEN(SPLIT([rTime],':',1))-2))
```

When I am dragging `CheckrTime` into workspace area, the output is coming in below format which is what I wanted :
`May 10, 2019`

1. When I am checking `ISDATE("May 10, 2019")` (a normal string), it is outputting `TRUE` as expected but when I am checking `ISDATE(CheckrTime)` it is outputting `FALSE` . **Why?**
2. The reason I am checking above thing is I am looking to use `DATEDIFF` function of tableau in this way:

```
   DATEDIFF('day', DATE(CheckrTime), TODAY()) == 0
```

`NOTE`

- If someone is wondering ,I have taken care of the level of granularity.
- If you have a better solution then the one I am following, please do tell me.

Comment: There is no Tableau 9.4 release, btw.  You must be on a different version.

Comment: @tagyoureit That's a mistake from my part and I have updated version to 10.4.3 in question.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.  I would expect May 10 <> May 16 (today) and therefore return false.  However, when I change your example to today's date it does in fact come back as true.

[image: Date calculation]

You could also try this formula for the date `LEFT([rTime],FINDNTH([rTime],' ',3))`.  It is slightly less complicated but will give you the same answer.

Comment: That is not working in my server. Now I think its happening because I am using a Tableau server with live connection. You might be working on Tableau Desktop with extracts. Although I am not sure.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if it is Desktop/Server or live/extract. Can you post some images or results after each calculation. It is really hard to help work only ,"it isn't working".

Answer (score 0):

Calculated field (date type)  depends the locale used which defines date format. Are you able to use Date function?

In Tableau website there is a example using english locale
For string  06May2017
DATE (LEFT([Original Date], 2) + "/" + MID([Original Date],3,3) + "/" + RIGHT([Original Date],4))

Above mentioned highligts / character between digits which is depending on locale